# Anyone using HyperDex in production?

Tags: nosql, hyperdex

I just noticed that the relatively new Open Source noSQL database "[HyperDex](http://hyperdex.org)" has no mentions in questions in S.O. yet - is someone using it? How does it compare with other noSQL engines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We're working with some folks at LinkedIn to use HyperDex to power some of their custom analytics applications.  We're also in discussion with a couple startups to build applications on top of HyperDex.

Our mailing list is the [HyperDex discuss list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/hyperdex-discuss) and has been relatively active as of late.  Many of these folks are using HyperDex and helping us to improve it.

Finally, HyperDex holds its own against other popular NoSQL engines.  The [HyperDex performance benchmarks](http://hyperdex.org/performance/) show that HyperDex offers both higher throughput and lower latency than other popular systems.  The HyperDex tutorials show just how easy it is to deploy a cluster.  Start with the QuickStart and work your way up to deploying a truly fault tolerant cluster.

Comment: Hello.  Did anybody compared Aerospike to Hyperdex in terms of speed or features?

Answer (score 3):

Emin gave a talk in our company today. Sounds interesting project, but I think you would encounter some gotchas if deploy in production, such as load balancing and optimal subspace scheme.

You can find the [performance comparison](http://hyperdex.org/performance/) at their site. The [paper](http://hyperdex.org/papers/) is also worth reading.